# How to do a boolean operation on a set of records using/via ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a task to determine if all boolean attributes of a subset of records are `true`. After using `sum`, I expected to have a similar method to work with booleans. However, I could not find such a thing.

I feel that there is a big chance that the answer is very clear, straightforward and available via a simple Google search, but I am not able to think of the correct phrases to search for it.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
[
  #<User id: 1, name: "John", arborist: true>,
  #<User id: 2, name: "Ben", arborist: true>,
  #<User id: 3, name: "Betty", arborist: false>,
]
```

Should return `false`

```
[
  #<User id: 1, name: "John", arborist: true>,
  #<User id: 2, name: "Ben", arborist: true>,
  #<User id: 3, name: "Betty", arborist: true>,
]
```

Should return `true`

---

At the moment I am using `count`.

```
all_arborists? = ( User.count == User.where(arborist: true).count )
```

It gets me the result, but I feel there is more to it than my mind can figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the records loaded in memory, and you're working with an Array, you can use Ruby's [`#all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#method-i-all-3F) method:

```rb
all_arborists = records.all? { |r| r.arborist }
```

If the records are in the DB and you don't want to load them in memory, then you need a SQL query, and what you tried is on the right path:

```rb
non_arborists = User.where(some_condition: foo).where(arborist: false).count
all_arborists = non_arborists == 0
```

Comment: Or shorter: `records.all?(&:arborist)`

Comment: I do like how this reads.

Comment: BroiSatse's query (Exists) is more efficient I think, it will stop scanning at the first record that is false, this query is a bit heavier as it counts all of them

Comment: @JoelBlum you are correct on the efficiency part however BroiSatse's solution does not scan it simply runs a query akin to "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE users.arborist = 0 LIMIT 1" and returns true if there is a record or false if not (which is then negated by the `!`). No actual records are loaded in the process. Additionally @tompave's solution will short circuit on the first non arborist so it does not need to cycle all of them unless a) they are all arborists; or b) only the last record is not an arborist.

Comment: To add to the discussion - this answer is still more efficient if the relation has been already loaded as it then requires 0 database calls - mine will always make a call (unless we merge those solutions together with an `if loaded?`

Comment: @BroiSatse to further continue "more efficient" could depend on the number of records and the existence and/or position of a "non-arborist". The `exists?` hit is very cheap and likely faster than finding a "non-arborist" at a high index position or not at all in a large data set. Another modification to the second example would be `User.where(some_condition: foo).where(arborist: false).any?` since `any?` (without a block) has special meaning to a AR::Relation and the result is effectively `.count > 0`.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply check if there is a single non-arborist in the database:

```
all_arborists = !User.exists?(arborist: false)
```

You can defined it as a class method, rails magic will make it available on all scopes:

```
class User
  def self.all_arborists?
    !exists?(arborist: false)
  end
end

User.where(some_condition: foo).all_arborists?
```

Comment: This is really neat!

Answer (score 1):

Use `:pluck` method on User class to fetch arborist column values, followed by array method `all?` to check if all values are true.

```
User.pluck(:arborist).all?
```